# Why does my Azure Function function key keep regenerating?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've got half a dozen different Azure Functions that are hit a few hundred times a day. One of them though, which is no different than any of the others really, has developed a new "feature". Every few days, it changes the function key.

This function key is used for authentication to the function, so it breaks our flows whenever it changes. The original key (and the one I keep setting it back to) is 56 characters in length. The new one is many times that length. I don't know why, but I would assume there is some kind of difference.

I can set the function key back to what it was, but a few days later, it happens again with no warning.

The key seems to change when the function is "in use". This function is used in a bursty manner. It won't be hit for a few days, then I'll make a few hundred requests over an hour, then stop again for a few hours, etc. Both times that they key changed, it was working just fine during one of these bursty periods, and changed mid way through.

So, why does the key change, and how can I stop it from doing so?

Note: All our other functions are just fine. None of them exhibit this same behavior.

Comment: Can you please check under "Platform features" => "Audit log" what happens to this specific Azure Function. Is there any deployment action happening (maybe bound to a tagging or commit trigger from a version control CI pipeline)?

Comment: Is it possible that  two function apps are pointed to same azure storage? Do you see *snapshot* (host.snapshot.2018-12-03 20.22.54.807089.json) files in your "azure-webjobs-secrets" container?

Comment: @SebastianAchatz I don't have "Audit Log" mentioned there. The closest I have is "Activity log", but it is empty for all time periods.

Comment: @AlexeyRodionov No, it's definitely just the one. All I have is `host.json` in a "folder" with the same name as the  app in the `azure-webjobs-secrets` container.

Comment: can you please share you function name privately:https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: `2018-12-04T23:04:21.600 [Info] Function started (Id=b6ed1d2f-dd38-4f63-8cc5-a41647a7616e)` Thanks.

Comment: What is the function app region?

Comment: Region is: West US 2

Comment: Was your issue resolved?
Did Alexey Rodionov help you?

Comment: It wasn't clear what the issue was. I removed the entire resource group and set it up again. Doing that appeared to fix the issue.